# external table preprocessor is not working

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, external-tables, plsql-package

--the preprocessor is showing as an error when in sql developer oracle 12G

```
CREATE TABLE WPP_EXT (
    ACCOUNT_ID  VARCHAR2(50),
    SER_NUM     VARCHAR2(100)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  default directory EXT_DIR
  access parameters (
      RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
      PREPROCESSOR EXEC_DIR: 'firstfilerename.bat'
    NOLOGFILE
    skip 1
    FIELDS TERMINATED by ',' 
           ( 
            ACCOUNT_ID, 
            DUMMY,
           DUMMY,
            SER_NUM
          )
  )
  LOCATION ('data_1.csv')
)
reject limit unlimited;
```

Comment: Specifically what error are you gettting? Are you getting the error when you create the table or when you select from it? The fact that you have two `DUMMY` columns is a red flag to me, but I'd have to look up the syntax.

Comment: it works fine without the preprocessor..  is it because my bat file is located on a network drive? though it is also defined in all directories

Comment: the table was successfully created, and it shows me this error when i select it ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04040: file data_1.csv in EXT_DIR not found
29913. 00000 -  "error in executing %s callout"
*Cause:    The execution of the specified callout caused an error.
*Action:   Examine the error messages take appropriate action.

Comment: Show the `CREATE DIRECTORY` command for EXEC_DIR, plus grants please?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY EXEC_DIR AS '/REPORT/WPP_EXT_DIR/EXEC';
GRANT ALL ON DIRECTORY EXEC_DIR TO PUBLIC;

Comment: the preprocessor line shows as an error in sql developer too

Comment: "EXEC_DIR" it should be execdir not exec_dir

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY EXECDIR AS '/REPORTBAU/WPP_EXT_DIR/EXEC';
grant all on directory EXECDIR to public;        PREPROCESSOR EXECDIR: 'firstfilerename.bat'             .. still in error

Comment: Your file is a .bat, so I assume Windows, but the path is using Linux syntax. Is that the right syntax to create a directory object under Windows?